# Symfony 2 form override and path / configuration solving

Tags: symfony, configuration

I'm very new to Symfony 2.
I'm trying to add some other custom form fields.

The bundle I'm using has been made this way:

```
src/TheClient/
`-- Bundle
    |-- MyBundle
    |   |-- Controller
    |   |-- DependencyInjection
    |   |-- Entity
    |   |-- Form
    |   |-- Repository
    |   |-- Resources
    |   `-- Tests
    `-- OtherNotImportantBundle
        |-- Command
        |-- Controller
        |-- DependencyInjection
        |-- Entity
        |-- Resources
        |-- Services
        `-- Tests
```

I've created the file `src/TheClient/Bundle/MyBundle/Resources/views/Form/fields.html.twig` where there is some code like this:

```
{% block form_row %}
    <div class="control-group">
        {{ form_label(form) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block text_widget %}
    <div class="text_widget controls">
        {% set type = type|default('text') %}
        {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

To make it short, it overrides the original form ressource to enclose it with `div`'s.
Now, what I'm supposed to do is just edit `app/config/config.yml` and precise the new form fields like this:

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%
    globals:
      sso_host: %sso_host%
      root_url: %root_url%
    form:
        resources:
            - 'TheClientMyBundle:Form:fields.html.twig'
#            - 'MyBundle:Form:fields.html.twig'
```

I've tried both solutions and they dont work, I get an error 500. I'm very new to Symfony 2. What are the steps, where should I look, to make it work?

I forgot to precise: I'm trying to follow [this tutoriel from the Symfony website itself](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html).

Thank you very much

Comment: It's a bit weird having a path like this `src/Client/Bundle/MyBundle`, you should have something looking like `src/Client/MyBundle`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is error message? "`Unable to find template...`"?

Resource name should be `MyBundleName:Form:fields.html.twig`

where `MyBundleName` is name of you bundle added inside `AppKernel.php` file

For example `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle()` bundle name is `FrameworkBundle`.

Comment: I'm sorry I wanted to remove my question because I've solved it. In the `fields.html.twig` file there's a use of the function `humanize` which is only available in the 2.1 and... guess what the client gave me the 2.0 version (the version I'm supposed to work on) and in-between they've upgraded to 2.1.